# What user permission is required to listen to port 8080

Tags: permissions, tcp-ip

I'm trying to run [Cuberite](https://cuberite.org/) under its own username, cuberite.  However, when I

```
sudo -u cuberite ./Cuberite
```

I'm unable to connect to it with my web browser:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :8080
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Cuberite 1091 ubuntu   25u  IPv6 469693      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
$ netstat -nla | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

But if I run it under my own login account ("ubuntu"), I can get through to it with my web browser:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :8080
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Cuberite 1152 ubuntu   25u  IPv6 469908      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
Cuberite 1152 ubuntu   26u  IPv6 469909      0t0  TCP ip-172-29-30-22.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:http-alt->123-243-56-42.static.tpgi.com.au:53169 (ESTABLISHED)
Cuberite 1152 ubuntu   27u  IPv6 469911      0t0  TCP ip-172-29-30-22.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:http-alt->123-243-56-42.static.tpgi.com.au:53170 (ESTABLISHED)
Cuberite 1152 ubuntu   28u  IPv6 469913      0t0  TCP ip-172-29-30-22.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:http-alt->123-243-56-42.static.tpgi.com.au:53171 (ESTABLISHED)
Cuberite 1152 ubuntu   29u  IPv6 469915      0t0  TCP ip-172-29-30-22.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:http-alt->123-243-56-42.static.tpgi.com.au:53173 (ESTABLISHED)
Cuberite 1152 ubuntu   30u  IPv6 469917      0t0  TCP ip-172-29-30-22.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:http-alt->123-243-56-42.static.tpgi.com.au:53172 (ESTABLISHED)
Cuberite 1152 ubuntu   31u  IPv6 469919      0t0  TCP ip-172-29-30-22.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal:http-alt->123-243-56-42.static.tpgi.com.au:53174 (ESTABLISHED)
$ netstat -nla | grep 8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

What is the difference between my login user and user cuberite, such that this behaviour is different? How can I find out differences between these accounts?

Comment: What I think is when you are trying to run it using `cuberite` user,  your `ubuntu` user is listening on the `8080` port. that's why the other user can't start listening. while you can't run it using `cuberite` user, run this command: `netstat -nla | grep 8080` add the output to your question.

Comment: @Ravexina These outputs are grabbed while running in a different terminal; there isn't any blocking going on that I know of. `netstat` output added.

Comment: You are right, I'm not sure what can be the cause of problem, however do as follow and see whats happens: 1- Make sure it's not running under `ubuntu` user. 2- Switch to `cuberite` user using `su - cuberite` 3- then try to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect with the correct protocol. Connecting to a HTTPS server on port 8080 by asking for the HTTP address (which is what will happen if you don't prefix your URL with HTTPS:// ) will time out, behaving the same as if the server isn't running at all.